# Numbering recurring elements that have the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that contains objects about the Lord of the Rings movies. The movie titles for each of the movies are recurring, and I need to find a way to number them, so the first movie is renamed "1. The Fellowship of the Ring", and the second movie becomes "2. The Two Towers", etc. This way worked successfully, however, I am looking for an alternative solution to this:

```
arr.forEach(element => {
      if(element[0] === "The Fellowship of the Ring"){
      newArray.push({"1. " + element[0]}) }}
```

Comment: do you have some more data to play with it?

Comment: You're going to have to give people more to go on than that. Nobody can guess what your source file looks like; it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
arr.map((title, i) => (i + 1) + " " + title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index from the loop

```
arr.map((element, index) => newArray.push(`${index + 1}. ${element}`));
```